# Calculate the sum of all possible combinations of n lists and check compare to specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a code (in python 3) that is able to calculate the sum of all possible combinations of a varying number of lists. The result of the sum needs to be checked with a specified value. For all combinations where the sum adds up to the specified value, I would like to create a new list containing just those values.

For example:

```
value = 5
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

1 + 2 = 3 - x
1 + 3 = 4 - x
1 + 4 = 5 - correct
1 + 5 = 6 - x
2 + 2 = 4 - x
2 + 3 = 5 - correct
...
```

The result should be for example:

```
res = [[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]]
```

I know that a simple option would be to use nested for-loops. The problem is that at the time of writing the code I dont know how many lists there will be, resulting in the need to define all possible cases. This is something I dont want to do. By the time I am running the code, I do know how many lists there are. The length of the lists will always be the same (26 elements).

The lists that need to be checked are stored in a list in the following way. For example:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

An example of an actual set of lists that I would like to solve this problem for is:

```
list = [[0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

All the zero values are the result of other refinements in the total number of options that do not meet other criterias.

I hope someone can push me into the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: this may give you a few ideas on how to iterate over combinations of elements in lists: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: What you describe as "all possible combinations of multiple lists" is called the Cartesian product, and you can get it with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Also, your result should be `res = [[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2]]`, since there's no 1 in list `b`.

Comment: I would also look at [`comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps), for `list` or `set` to help build your results, they support an `if` clause which would help filter out the results to the ones you want.

Answer (score 3):

With some list of lists `l` (don't name something `list`, there's a built in function named `list`)

```
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

We can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all combinations of items between the lists, then [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function onto those combinations.  Then checking for membership is easy.

```
from itertools import product

if value in map(sum, product(*l)):
    print('Yes!')
else:
    print('No :(')
```

If you want to save the sums for multiple checks, I recommend saving them into a set

```
sum_set = set(map(sum, product(*l)))
if value in sum_set:
    ...
```

The `*` in `product(*l)` takes the is the unpacking operator.  It gives the elements of `l` to `product` as individual arguments `product([1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5])`

Comment: OP didn't ask for a list of the sums, so wouldn't `[p for p in product(*l) if sum(p) == value]` or something like that be better?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'd probably do `list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == value, product(*l)))` but you're right, I didn't read the requirements all the way

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you prefer `filter` to a comprehension? Readability?

Comment: I did a lot of functional programming for  a while, so that style is what i default to.  Plus, setting up generator chains is very natural in python 3.  It's more preference than anything else, and probably slower than the comprehension